# How to speed up the user swiping to trigger a refresh in flutter's Refreshindicator

Tags: flutter

If the user uses the default setting of the Refreshindicator, and the finger needs to pull down a long distance to trigger the refresh action, how can we speed up the process?

I tried to decrease the displacement value, but it only changed the distance between the refresh indicator and the top of the child element, not the actual distance the user swiped.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [custom_refresh_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator) package.

The parameter `offsetToArmed` represents the pixel distance at which the refresh is triggered.

Example:

```
return CustomRefreshIndicator(
      child: widget.child,
      offsetToArmed: 20,   // << Change it to whatever fit your requirement
      builder: MaterialIndicatorDelegate(
        builder: (context, controller) {
          return Icon(
            Icons.ac_unit,
            color: Colors.blue,
            size: 30,
          );
        },
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. This is possible. But custom_refresh_indicator tip me: 'MaterialIndicatorDelegate' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. In favor of CustomMaterialIndicator widget. So I went to use CustomMaterialIndicator, but I couldn't find the offsetToArmed parameter inside CustomMaterialIndicator. If I want to use CustomRefreshIndicator, I have to write my own Indicator, but I can't, I just want a simple refresh animation, like Refreshindicator, is there a better way?